# UK sponsor for tourist visa

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, visa-sponsors

My cousin is a UK national, living in the UK. He wants to sponsor me and my family for a short-stay visa, around 2 weeks. He will bear all my expenses during my stay in the UK, accommodation, transportation, food and maintenance, etc.

Also, the cricket world Cup 2019 is near. We are also planning to watch these matches. Do I have chances to get a visa or is it just 50/50?

NOTE: If someone has any UK-based invitation letter format, please send me.

Answer (score 4):

In spite of your cousin sponsoring you to visit the UK, the onus is on you to satisfy the Entry Clearance Officer that you have sufficient reasons to go back to your home country.

You job/business, family ties in your native country etc. will be considered. Your bank statement must have regular credits and debits.

If your personal credentials are weak, you may think of not taking your whole family with you. You may leave your children with your parents or other relatives back in your home country and visit with your wife only. This will prove sufficient reasons for you to return from the UK. In this case you will have to provide the passport copies and other details of your children with your visa application.

Answer (score 4):

A successful application typically shows a credible reason for the visit, strong ties to home that will compel the applicant to leave the UK at the end of their stay (job, family, property, savings etc), and sound financial standing. Having a sponsor does not remove the need for the applicant to demonstrate that they qualify for a visa in their own right. It may help you to review the Visit Guidance https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visit-guidance and this excellent answer [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) on the most common triggers for a U.K. visa refusal before deciding whether to apply.
There is no standard format for an invitation letter. Your sponsor should also provide a covering letter addressed to the Entry Clearance Officer to explain the background to the invitation, for example why they are inviting you, their relationship to you, confirmation that they will provide maintenance & accommodation  and have the capacity to do so.